# How to replace substrings of a string outside of ""

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string like:

```
'a, b, "c,d" e, f,'
```

I would like to split my string using the comma character as separator, but outside of the brackets. My result object set should contain the following elements:

```
a
b
"c,d" e
f
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
s = 'a, b, "c,d" e, f,';
console.log(s.match(/("[^"]+"|[^,])+/g));
```

yields `[ 'a', ' b', ' "c,d" e', ' f' ]`, which has extra spaces, but you can trim them.

**Edit:** missed the `e`... now fixed.

**Explanation:**

- `(A|B)+` prefers `A` (which is a quoted string) instead of B, which is a non-quoted part of the string.  It matches `"c,d"`, then because of the `+` it continues matching `e`.
- `"[^"]+"` matches a `"` followed by all the non-`"`, followed by a single `"`.
- `[^,]` matches any non-`"`
- `/regex/g` makes global (matches all matches, not just the first)

Comment: +1, because it works, I also accept this answer, thank you very much. However, can you explain this regex? Thank you again.

Comment: @LajosArpad, I added an explanation... hope it helps.